# Spring AWS SQS - MessageConversionException

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs

I am trying to resolve serializing problem with SQS Queue, here is a code:

```
@Configuration
public class QueueConfig {

    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs, ResourceIdResolver resourceIdResolver) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();

        DefaultContentTypeResolver resolver = new DefaultContentTypeResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setSerializedPayloadClass(String.class);
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSqs, resourceIdResolver, converter);
    }
}
```

This works (String):

```
public void publish(String queue, String value) {
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, value);
}
```

This doesn't work (Object):

```
public void publish(String queue, Something something) {
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, something);
}
```

I get error:

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Unable to convert payload with type='com.example.Something', contentType='null', converter=[CompositeMessageConverter[converters=[org.springframework.messaging.converter.StringMessageConverter@433f5e00, org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter@74e3e86e]]]
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd suspect, this piece of code

```
converter.setSerializedPayloadClass(String.class);
```

Just try doing this rather

```
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSqs, resourceIdResolver, converter);
```

This will convert request body to byte[] before publishing the message to queue.